# Декод текста из бинарного кода

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary

Хочу сделать из бинарного кода строку через Python. Искал методы, но они все для кодов без пробелов. А у меня бинарный код с пробелами.
Я декодировал строку `lol` в `1101100 1101111 1101100` и хочу снова превратить её в `lol` через Python

```py
x = "1101100 1101111 1101100"
somethingtodecode(x)
```

Comment: Для начала просто удалите из строки пробелы с помощью цикла, а дальше на полученный результат используйте способы, которые вы знаете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = "1101100 1101111 1101100"
res = "".join([chr(int(i,2)) for i in x.split()])
print(res)
```

> lol

Answer (score 1):

Декодирование

```
x="1101100 1101111 1101100"
bytes( int(p,base=2) for p in x.split() ).decode()
```

Один из способов кодирования

```
" ".join(bin(a).lstrip('0b') for a in 'lol'.encode())
```

А ещё можно удалить пробелы, только не забудь ведущие нули добавить при кодировании.